# postgres accessing database tables where the data base has a schema

Tags: postgresql

have 4 databases one of them is named REBAR
under rebar there are two schemas one named public and one named sw
under sw there are 10 table.

this statement shows me all data bases

```
SELECT datname from pg_database
```

this statement returns []

```
self.curs.execute("""select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'sw' ;""")
tables = self.curs.fetchall()
```

Comment: `datname` is something different then `schema_name`. If the select doesn't return anything then apparently you don't have any tables in the schema  `sw`. What does `select schema_name from information_schema.schemata` return?

Comment: Are you connecting to the same db cluster?

Comment: Apologies - I was not certain the best way to present my dliemna. Maybe this will help. The tree given by Pgadmin III shows the following:

Comment: Apologies - I was not certain the best way to present my dliemna. Maybe this will help. The tree given by Pgadmin III shows the following: Servers (1) - PostgresSQL 9.2 (localhost:5432) - Databases(4) - REBAR - Schemas (2)  - public- sw -   ... Tables (10)

Comment: Thank you for your responses - I found my difficulty. I was connecting to the postgres instead of database 'REBAR'.

Comment: Once again an apology for taking up your valuable time answering silly questions.